# Terminal results

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I would like to post part or all of a Terminal result (i.e. Sudo apt get update). How does one capture some or all of the data in the Terminal and paste it into Ask Ubuntu? Also, if there is a way, will it have the same appearance as the Terminal text (font, line returns etc)?

Comment: Of the methods in the dupe, even though `pastebinit` is the top-voted, I'd suggest that you use it only if the output is *very* long. For most use cases, copying directly to the post and applying [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) would be preferable, since we like to posts to be as self-contained as possible.

Answer (score 2):

- If you are not using English, it will help us understand the output, if you set the language in the terminal to English with the following command

  ```
  LANG=C
  ```
- In many terminal windows you can **mark everything** via the dropdown menu 'Edit', and then use the same dropdown menu to **copy** it (to the clipboard).

  An alternative is to install the program page `xclip` and then **pipe** the output to the program `xclip` as shown in the following example,

  ```
  sudo apt install xclip
  sudo lsblk -fm | xclip -selection clipboard
  ```
- After that you can **paste** it into the editing window of AskUbuntu.
- Finally you can **render it as 'code'** either with the icon **`{}`** above the editing window or by indenting each line four spaces. If the surrounding text is already indented you need to indent eight spaces.

Comment: OP could also directly pipe the output to `xclip` with e.g. `sudo apt update | xclip -selection clipboard` to save the first step.

Comment: Also you could mention the setting `LANG=C` to get english output.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @dessert. I will edit my answer :-)